# Can I change and commit the state inside settimeout function in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, settimeout

```html
form(@submit.prevent="onSubmit")
   input(type="text" v-model="platform" placeholder="Add platform name...")
   input(type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" @click="clicked = true")
   button(type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn" @click="cancelNew") Cancel      
      h3(v-if="clicked")  Thank you for adding a new platform 
         span {{ countdown }}
```

This is my template and when the user submits the form, I want to count down from 3 using setTimeout function and submit after 3 seconds.

If I have it this way, it works;

```js
data() {
  return {
    countdown: 3,
    platform: ""
  }
},
methods: {
  countDownTimer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.countdown -= 1
      this.countDownTimer()
    }, 1000)
  },
  onSubmit() {
    let newplatform = {
      name: this.platform
    }
    this.addPlatform(newplatform)
    this.platform = ' ' 
    this.countDownTimer()
  }
}
```

However I have 3 more forms and I didn't want to repeat the code. So I wanted to put countdown in the store,

```
countDownTimer({commit}) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    countdown = state.countdown
    countdown -= 1
    commit('COUNTDOWN', countdown)
    this.countDownTimer()
  }, 1000)
}
```

and mutate it like

```
COUNTDOWN(state, countdown) {
  state.countdown = countdown
}
```

This doesn't work and I am not sure If I am able to change the state, commit the changes inside of settimeout function? Is there a better way I can implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues:

1. The recursive `setTimeout` isn't stopped.
2. The countdown timer isn't reset.
3. Use `setInterval` (and `clearInterval`) instead of the recursive `setTimeout`.
4. For async logic including `setTimeout`, use an action rather than a mutation.
5. Include `state` from the context object (where you get `commit`), or it will be undefined.

Try this:

```js
actions: {
  countDownTimer({ state, commit, dispatch }) {  // state, commit, dispatch
    commit('RESET');
    const interval = setInterval(() => {         // Use `setInterval` and store it
      commit('COUNTDOWN');
      if (state.countdown === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);                 // Clear the interval
        dispatch('updateDatabase');              // Call another action
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

```
mutations: {
  RESET(state) {
    state.countdown = 3;
  },
  COUNTDOWN(state) {
    state.countdown--;
  }
}
```